# Does stringstream.read() consume the stream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I can't tell from the documentation how `std::stringstream.read()` works. Does it consume the stream or not?

In other words:

```
std::stringstream ss;
char buffer[6];

ss << "Hello world!";
ss.read(buffer, 6);

std::cout << ss.str(); // Is this "Hello world!" or just "world!"
```

Comment: You *could* always try this, right?

Comment: Touche @KerrekSB. But there was more to understand. The `str()` function returns the underlying buffer regardless of the stream position, whereas subsequent calls to `read()` will continue to advance the stream (see answer below). Testing my example code gave me a wrong impression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The member `std::istream::read()` advances the stream position for as many characters it returns. I guess, this is what you mean with "consuming the stream". After reading 6 characters from `ss`, the next character read will be the `w`.

However, the string stream's internal buffer is still the entire string, i.e., the result of `str()` is unaffected by the read position: `std::stringstream::str()` returns all characters. In 27.8.2.3 [stringbuf.members] paragraph 1 it says:

> `basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator> str() const;`
>
> Returns: A basic_string object whose content is equal to the basic_stringbuf underlying character sequence. ...

The paragraph goes on describing what the underlying character sequence is but it amounts to: the entire original string in input mode and the original characters plus additional written characters in output mode.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I just tried my snippet on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp0x_online.php and got "Hello world!" which seems to indicate the stream position was not advanced. Unless I'm not understanding something.

Comment: @chowey: Please read the entire answer, not just the first paragraph: The read position will be advanced but `str()` will still return the entire string. With respect to being sure: the quote above is taken from the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882-2011). If an implementation deviates, it isn't standard conforming.

Comment: Thanks I am tracking now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it consumes the stream.
However str() function returns complete string in buffer.
You can use ss.rdbuf()->in_avail() to get size of data available after read/>> operations:

```
ss << "Hello world!";
ss.read(buffer, 6);

std::cout << ss.rdbuf()->in_avail(); // 6 characters available ("world!").
```

Answer (score -1):

`read` is an unformmatted input function; it extracts a specified amount of characters from the internal buffer into the byte array that you supply. In this case, it extracts 6 characters from the buffer into `buffer`. So the content of `buffer` will be `"Hello "`.

The opposite goes for `write`. `write` will insert a specified amount of characters from the supplied byte array into the internal buffer of the output stream.